# How to install older package of ansible?

Tags: ansible, rpm, yum

I need to install `ansible 2.1.0.0-1.el7`. My setup does not work with the newest version of ansible which I installed with:

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel install ansible
```

This gave me `ansible-2.2.0.0-3.el7.noarch`. So I tried to list the older versions but I could not find them:

```
# yum -y --enablerepo=epel --showduplicates list ansible
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror2.hs-esslingen.de
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: it.centos.contactlab.it
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
Available Packages
ansible.noarch                    2.2.0.0-3.el7                                epel
```

[This is a site](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ansible) where I found multiple versions but I don't know how to install it.

Can someone help me to install the Ansible version I need?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should install it with python pip.

```
sudo yum install python-pip python-devel python
```

And then:

```
sudo pip install pip --upgrade
sudo pip install ansible==2.1.0.0
```

And now you should be able to use:

```
ansible-playbook ...
```

If you don't manage to install pip with the command I gave you, have a look here: https://packaging.python.org/install_requirements_linux/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I was able to install the python stuff. But what I actually need to use is ansible-playbook which I can't find anymore

Comment: Hello. Yeah now you should be able to run the pip command. It will install ansible and then you can run ansible-playbook. You may need to upgrade pip before you use it and use sudo, I am going to edit my answer so you can try it.

Comment: Did your commands successfully but: /usr/bin/ansible-playbook: No such file or directory

Comment: Probably because it was not run as sudo, can you try the new commands I wrote?

Comment: I ran everything as root user (only user on my machine at the moment).

Comment: Weird, maybe it's because it was first installed with yum then pip. Can you run "pip show ansible"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128384/discussion-between-bruno-b-carvalho-and-maxc).